# Kafka Template: Timeout Exception while sending the message by kafka template

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

In spring boot project using kafka template to send the message

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;


@Service
@Slf4j
class KafkaMessagePublisherImpl {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate kafkaAsyncPublisher;

    public void sendMessage() {
        ListenableFuture listenableFuture = kafkaAsyncPublisher.send(
                "test_topikc",
                "key_1",
                "{\"greeting\":\"Hello\"}");

        listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<?, ?>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final SendResult<?, ?> message) {
                System.out.println("Sent");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {

                System.out.println("Message sending failed");

            }
        });

    }


    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "brokers1:9092,brokers2:9092");
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }


    @Bean(name = "kafkaAsyncPublisher")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaAsyncPublisher() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

While using the `sendMessage` method in another class, the following error is coming

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$1.onCompletion(KafkaTemplate.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:760)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:701)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:245)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:157)
    at com.tesco.fps.messaging.service.impl.KafkaMessagePublisherImpl.lambda$sendMessage$0(KafkaMessagePublisherImpl.java:52)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

`Springboot:1.5.10.RELEASE` and `compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:0.11.0.0')` are being used as gradle dependency along with `spring-cloud-stream`

Comment: This error usually means you have incorrectly configured your Producer which is not able to communicate with Kafka service. It is evident from the root of the exception which is in Kafka itself. Look in your application logs and the kafka service logs to see what the actual error is.

Comment: is Kafka brokers are running on this host and port number? brokers1:9092,brokers2:9092?

Comment: @Himeshgoswami Yes brokers on brokers1:9092,brokers2:9092

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Log is not giving any useful details.

Comment: All I am saying is that this is not a Spring issue, rather Kafka configuration issue. If you search Google for "Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms." you'll see that it's one of the more common configuration issues that developers experience, but the causes/solutions vary so consider doing some research as well . . .

Comment: It's often caused by mismatched SSL/plain text configuration but, as Oleg said, the causes vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only minor change was done to make it working

```
@Service
@Slf4j
class KafkaMessagePublisherImpl {
   @Autowired
   private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaAsyncPublisher;
   //Rest is same.

}
```